# Missing values Jarque Bera test in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform the Jarque Bera test on  hourly and daily return series in R. It worked fine for my daily return series, however it doesn't work for high frequency data.

That's what I did so far:

```
# Daily,hourly,minute prices of Tether in USD
df.ohlc.daily_usdt <- get_ohlc(usdt, periods = 86400, after = "2014-01-01",     datetime=TRUE)
df.ohlc.hourly_usdt <- get_ohlc(usdt, periods = 3600, after = "2014-01-01", datetime = TRUE)
df.ohlc.min_usdt <- get_ohlc(usdt, periods = 60, after = "2014-01-01", datetime = TRUE)

index_daily_usdt <- df.ohlc.daily_usdt$CloseTime
data_daily_usdt <- data.frame(df.ohlc.daily_usdt[,2:6])
df.ohlc.daily_usdt_xts <- xts(data_daily_usdt, index_daily_usdt)
usdt_daily_return <- dailyReturn(df.ohlc.daily_usdt_xts, log=TRUE)

index_hour_usdt <- df.ohlc.hourly_usdt$CloseTime
data_hour_usdt <- data.frame(df.ohlc.hourly_usdt[,2:6])
df.ohlc.hourly_usdt_xts <- xts(data_hour_usdt, index_hour_usdt)
usdt_hourly_return <- diff(log(Cl(df.ohlc.hourly_usdt_xts)), lag=1)

#Descriptive statistics Tether hourly log returns
usdt_mean_hourly = mean(usdt_hourly_return, na.rm = TRUE)
usdt_sd_hourly = sd(usdt_hourly_return, na.rm = TRUE)
usdt_min_hourly = min(usdt_hourly_return, na.rm = TRUE)
usdt_max_hourly = max(usdt_hourly_return, na.rm = TRUE)

usdt_JB_hourly = jarque.bera.test(usdt_hourly_return)

Error in jarque.bera.test(usdt_hourly_return) : NAs in x
```

The JB test using Desctools does not work for me. Can someone tell me what other possibility I have to remove NAs to perform the JB test using ts package?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DescTools::JarqueBeraTest(usdt_hourly_return, na.rm=TRUE)
```

does not work?

Comment: Unfortunately not since I'm still working with R 3.3.3 ( I have a pretty old macbook and can't update my R)...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29443573)

Comment: @Nick: It's an answer. It's just confusingly written. It's basically saying, "Can you not do this?" not "I tried this, why doesn't it work?" (From the author's response, it seems like it doesn't solve the problem, but that's a separate issue.)